# How do I refer IAM user name in lambda event?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've an AWS Lambda function which just prints the event

```
import json
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def respond(err, res=None):
    return {
        'statusCode': '400' if err else '200',
        'body': err.message if err else json.dumps(res),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('Received event: %s' + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    param1 = event['queryStringParameters']['name']
    param2 = event['queryStringParameters']['age']
    return respond(None, res='Hello World! event-----> ' + str(event) + "\n" + str(param1) + " 
    " + str(param2))
```

I've an API endpoint that calls this function and I can invoke the API like this.

```
https://abvdsa9gpa.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/?name=my-name&age=30
```

Now I want to access the IAM user name (possibly the email of the user) and then do some operations (sending email etc) to the user who accessed this end point from within my company.
So if someother user within my team accesses this end point, they should receive a test e-mail(SES part yet to be done), but first is there an easy way to identify the user who accessed this end point?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using IAM Authentication with API Gateway?  If not, no IAM user has been provided to authenticate the request.

Comment: What API authentication technique is used by the user? Typically the user has to prove that they are the user and they need to use 
- API Keys, OAuth 2.0, HTTP headers or JSON web tokens to authenticate

How are the users accessing the API? If they are using a IAM user and executing a program within AWS(say EC2 or Lambda) versus accessing the API from corporate network or internet?

$context.identity.user in API Gateway can provide user information . check if that helps - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Comment: We're invoking the lambda from corporate network. The API endpoint is working correctly when invoked from a browser. All I want is to capture the user who invoked the lambda. I tried printing context.identity.user from lambda handler function and it errored out "CognitoIdentity' object has no attribute 'user'". But event['requestContext'] prints userArn when tested from AWS Console. UserArn is null when invoked from a browser. I believe if I want to expose the end point from a browser, I need Cognito user pool and integrate the API with that? Sorry I am new to this, so don't have much idea.

Comment: 'capture the user who invoked the lambda' - how is the user identified? you mention a 'browser' - do they login? how?

Comment: They really don't login. They should be able to invoke the endpoint URL successfully from a browser. That's all. Also this endpoint should not be accessable from outside our corporate network (no public access). Not sure if that is possible??